# Why won't iPhoto open after upgrading to Lion?

Tags: macos, photos.app, crash

So, I just downloaded and installed Lion on my iMac. However, I did so on a separate clean partition, and saved Snow Leopard on the other. So, in Lion, I tried to open iPhoto on my Snow Leopard partition, and it crashed. Here's the error message:

com.apple.iPhoto: dyld: Library not loaded:      /Library/Frameworks/iLifeFaceRecognition.framework/Versions/A/iLifeFaceRecognition

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is from 2010, I think that it will work:

You need to re-install iPhoto because it's missing parts of itself:

To re-install iPhoto

1. Put the iPhoto.app in the trash (Drag it from your Applications Folder to the trash)
2. Go to HD/Library/Receipts and remove any pkg file there with iPhoto in the name. On 10.6 those receipts may be found in the Finder using the Go menu and selecting Go To Folder

In the resulting window type

/var/db/receipts/

1. Re-install.

If you purchased an iLife Disk, then iPhoto is on it.

If iPhoto was installed on your Mac when you go it then it’s on the System Restore disks that came with your Mac. Insert the first one and opt to ‘Install Bundled Applications Only.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2658126?threadID=2658126

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it. It's really a iPhoto 9.1.5, Time Machine backup/restore and Lion upgrade issue.

To fix my problem I:

1. Delete my iPhoto Library on my HD
2. Restore the latest iPhoto Library from Time Machine
3. Delete iPhoto software
4. Reinstall iPhoto with my iLife 11 DVD
5. Start iPhoto, but it asked me to upgrade from Internet. I did.
6. With iPhoto 9.1, I started it and bingo, the issue is fixed.
7. After a few tests, I did another software update to have the latest iPhoto version, 9.1.5

I tried many things the past two days, but only the steps described here worked.

Hope it will help you.

Serge

Answer (score 0):

My iPhoto crashed as well.
However, if I turned off photo stream in iCloud it loaded iPhoto OK.
Not a final fix obviously but a temporary solution to get up and running.

Comment: The original question was related to a quite specific setup issue (installation of Lion on a separate partition). I assume it's a different problem in your case. If you expect somebody to help you resolve it you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

the 3ivx codec is causing crashes on iPhoto 11, 9.2 when Photostream is activated. Try remove it from

HD/ Library/ Application Support